# How to convert unicode to utf-8 encoding in c#

Tags: c#, unicode, utf-8

I want to convert unicode string to UTF8 string. I want to use this UTF8 string in SMS API to send unicode SMS. 
I want conversion like this tool 
https://cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf8_encode

eg. I have unicode string "हैलो फ़्रेंड्स" and it should be converted into "à¤¹à¥à¤²à¥ à¥à¥à¤°à¥à¤à¤¡à¥à¤¸"

I have tried this but not getting expected output

```
    private string UnicodeToUTF8(string strFrom)
        {
           byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strFrom);

           return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        }
```

and calling function like this

```
string myUTF8String = UnicodeToUTF8("हैलो फ़्रेंड्स");
```

Comment: hrmm `ASCII` is not `utf-8` on the best of days

Comment: tried this too byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Comment: @satyender replace `Encoding.Default` with `Encoding.UTF8` and then use the resulting `byte[]` array as-is, don't pass it back to `GetString()` at all. Which SMS API are you using exactly? If it supports Unicode properly, it should be taking a Unicode string as input and handle the UTF-8 encoding internally for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is possible to answer concretely without knowing more about the SMS API you want to use.  The `string` type in C# is UTF-16. If you want a different encoding, it's given to you as a `byte[]` (because a `string` is UTF-16, always).

You *could* 'cast' that into a string by doing something like this:

```
static string UnicodeToUTF8(string from) {
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(from);
    return new string(bytes.Select(b => (char)b).ToArray());
}
```

As far as I can tell this yields the same output as the website you linked. However, without knowing what API you're handing this string off to, I can't guarantee that this will ultimately work.

The point of `string` is that we don't need to worry about its underlying encoding, but this casting operation is kind of a giant hack and makes no guarantees that `string` represents a well-formed string anymore.

If something expects a UTF-8 encoding, it should accept a `byte[]`, not a `string`.

Comment: thanks its working its returning the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string output = "hello world";
byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(output));
byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(output));
var output1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes1);
var output2 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes2);
```

You will see that bytes1 is 11 bytes (1 byte per char UTF-8) and bytes2 is 22 bytes (2 bytes per char for unicode)